# How to read console logs of each pod in OpenShift (OKD) and forward it via syslog?

Tags: kubernetes, logging, openshift, syslog, okd

I have an OKD in my home server, and running few deployments on it. I don't want to log into file only in console, and wants to send them with syslog.

I already made that each pod sends its own logs, but this means, i have to add every microservice a logging. (for eg. need maven dependency to send logs from spring boot project to syslog)

What I want is something that collects logs from the cluster/project and send it to another outside server.

Is it possible somehow?

Thanks for all of your answers in advance!

Comment: OKD has a feature to forward log to a syslog server. Is it the way you would like to use?
https://docs.okd.io/latest/logging/cluster-logging-external.html#cluster-logging-collector-log-forward-syslog_cluster-logging-external